# Highcharts async drilldown for multiple levels of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, highcharts

Setting up a highchart that can call an API for multiple levels of data asynchronously.  On-click of data points, I want the highchart to "addSeriesAsDrilldown" while keeping all drillup events and chart options intact.

This is for a data-set with a hierarchical architecture.  For example, if I want the top 10 R&B hits of May 2010, my data will first show data points like this:
R&B

And then click 2010 data point:
R&B^2010

And then click May data point:
R&B^2010^May

We have used addSeriesAsDrilldown, but it only helps us for the first level of data.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
            drilldown: function (e) {
                if (!e.seriesOptions) {

                    var chart = this,
                        drilldowns = {
                            'Animals': {
                                name: 'Animals',
                                data: [
                                    {name: 'Sheep',
                                     y:5,
                                     drilldown: true
                                   },
                                    ['Cow', 3]
                                ]
                            },
                            'Fruits': {
                                name: 'Fruits',
                                data: [
                                    ['Apples', 5],
                                    ['Oranges', 7],
                                    ['Bananas', 2]
                                ]
                            },
                            'Cars': {
                                name: 'Cars',
                                data: [
                                    ['Toyota', 1],
                                    ['Volkswagen', 2],
                                    ['Opel', 5]
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        series = drilldowns[e.point.name];

                    // Show the loading label
                    chart.showLoading('Simulating Ajax ...');

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        chart.hideLoading();
                        chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
                    }, 1000);
                }

            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Async drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: true
        }, {
            name: 'Fruits',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: true
        }, {
            name: 'Cars',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: true
        }]
    }],

    drilldown: {
        series: []
    }
});
```

Expecting our output to have correct data as we drillup and down, without breaking the chart.

Comment: Hi @Alec Breton, The multiple level async drilldown seems to work properly. Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8he1L7yu/ (Animals -> Cars).

Comment: @ppotaczek how would the data get added asynchronously on-click of a chart element though?  Just added to the drilldown attribute?  Does it need to be formatted in a certain way?

Comment: You just need to use `addSeriesAsDrilldown` method. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fg6aqn8w/